# Absolute Position Based on Count of Triggering Element

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following format for a `flexbox` list, each item of which, when clicked, reveals a hidden div:

```
<ul class="items definitions">
        <li class="list__item closed" data-gk-close-span-glyph="active" data-gk-open-span-glyph=
        "closed" data-gk-open-class="3" data-gk-area-state="closed">Thing One</li>

        <li style="list-style: none">
            <div class="response-definition 3" style="display: none;">
                <p>One Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
            </div>
        </li>
```

The problem is that if I leave positioning as `static`, the revealed `div` will displace the items in the flexbox list. I don't want the hidden divs to be children of the list items which seems to leave me in the position of placing the hidden divs relative to the `ul` list itself.

This is a [pen for what I'm dealing with](http://codepen.io/MikeiLL/pen/YWpbVP).

Is there a way to change the position of the div based on the count of the list items? Something like this?

```
@for $i from 1 through length($mylist) {
     li:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
             top: $i * 5em;
     }
}
```

This would also need to be different for each media query as the number of columns changes.

Comment: exactly where you want to show the hidden divs  ?? under all li items ?? under the clicked li item? under the clicked item and offset the others?

Comment: Pretty much right under the clicked list item.

Comment: Without offsetting the other list items, if that's what you mean

Comment: Why would you not want them to be within the same list item? That would make things easier I would have thought

Comment: Same list item might make sense if the "button" was a separate item from the list item. I want different styling on buttons and the revealed divs.

Comment: We could still do that if we wrap the button in a button element or another div for example, I could show what I mean if you want by modifying your code

Comment: That would be really awesome. Then I can change the title of the question if you'd like to post an answer.

Comment: Updated, sorry for the delay, got busy with some work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the first four li elements for demo purpose, markup wise. Which means the rest of them are temporarily broken in my demo, but you should be able to see it working based off of this. Could clean up the css a bit after removing the remaining items as well.

What changes I made:

```
<li class="list__item active" data-gk-close-span-glyph="active" data-gk-open-span-glyph=
    "closed" data-gk-open-class="8" data-gk-area-state="closed">Thing Six</li>

<li style="list-style: none">
      <div class="response-definition 8" style="display: none;">
        <p>Six Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam urna urna, pretium eu
        pretium in, dictum nec nisl. Proin vehicula convallis mi, in vestibulum magna laoreet eget.
        Duis quis dignissim nibh, at aliquet elit. Mauris ultrices a sapien quis hendrerit.
        Pellentesque in nisi dui. Pellentesque commodo diam sapien, eget egestas elit rutrum
        sodales. Etiam sapien nisi, pretium eu consequat ut, sollicitudin vitae erat.</p>
      </div>
</li>
```

New list item structure:

```
<li class="list__item">
      <button class="btn active" data-gk-close-span-glyph="active" data-gk-open-span-glyph=
    "closed" data-gk-open-class="4" data-gk-area-state="closed">Thing Two</button>

      <div class="response-definition 4" style="display: none;">
        <p>Two Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam urna urna, pretium eu
        pretium in, dictum nec nisl. Proin vehicula convallis mi, in vestibulum magna laoreet eget.
        Duis quis dignissim nibh, at aliquet elit. Mauris ultrices a sapien quis hendrerit.
        Pellentesque in nisi dui. Pellentesque commodo diam sapien, eget egestas elit rutrum
        sodales. Etiam sapien nisi, pretium eu consequat ut, sollicitudin vitae erat.</p>
      </div>
</li>
```

Also modified css to:

```
.active, .closed {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.response-definition {
  max-width: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: 10px;
  //left: 20px;
  }

.list__item .btn:hover, .list__item .btn:hover:focus
{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: all 1s;
  color: tomato;
}
```

Remove these:

```
.response-definition:nth-of-type(1) {
  //top: 5em;
}

.response-definition:nth-of-type(2) {
  //top: 10em;
  }
```

Once you modify all you could probably change this:

```
.items .list__item {
  background: #e0ddd5;
  color: #171e42;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

To:

```
.items .list__item {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Here is the codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MebMQg

Comment: Very Nice. I updated the javascript code (first few lines) to match your changes and forked: http://codepen.io/MikeiLL/pen/zBNOQV